# Vue js with axios - unexpected behaviour

Tags: vue.js, axios

My WORKING piece of code in Vue js:

```
async mounted() {
            const token = this.$store.getters.loggedUser.token;

            incidents.getIncidentById(token, this.incidentId).then((resp) => {
                this.incidentData = resp.data;
            });

            incidents.getAllCriteria(token, this.incidentId)
                .then(resp => {
                    this.allCriteria = resp.data;
                })
                .then(() => {
                    this.sortAscendingByViolationCriteriumAndFactor();
                    this.setFactorCheckboxes();
                })
                .then(() => {
                    this.allCriteria.forEach(criteria => {
                        criteria.violationFactors.forEach(factor => {
                            this.setStateOfTheSameFactorsWithPlusAndMinus(factor);
                        });
                    });
                });
        },
```

Could you please explain me why the version below version doesn't work? I mean the method **setStateOfTheSameFactorsWithPlusAndMinus** doesn't work in this case (the method **setStateOfTheSameFactorsWithPlusAndMinus** is removed from this piece of code and moved to the method **setFactorCheckboxes**):

```
    async mounted() {
                const token = this.$store.getters.loggedUser.token;

                incidents.getIncidentById(token, this.incidentId).then((resp) => {
                    this.incidentData = resp.data;
                });

                incidents.getAllCriteria(token, this.incidentId)
                    .then(resp => {
                        this.allCriteria = resp.data;
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        this.sortAscendingByViolationCriteriumAndFactor();
                        this.setFactorCheckboxes();
                    })
            },

 methods: {
            setFactorCheckboxes() {
                this.allCriteria.forEach(criteria => {
                    criteria.violationFactors.forEach(factor => {
                        this.selectDegree(factor);
this.setStateOfTheSameFactorsWithPlusAndMinus(factor); //doesn't work here!!!
                    });
                    this.updateScoreForCriteria(criteria);
                });
        }


 setStateOfTheSameFactorsWithPlusAndMinus(factor) {
                if (factor.factor.includes('(+)') || factor.factor.includes('(-)')) {
                    let checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox' + factor.factor);
                    let factorName = factor.factor;
                    let factorType = factorName.slice(factorName.length - 3, factorName.length);
                    let checkboxBasicName = factorName.slice(0, factorName.length - 3);
                    let checkboxToFindAndChangeState = checkboxBasicName.concat(factorType === '(+)' ? '(-)' : '(+)');
                    let checkboxToDisable = document.getElementById('checkbox' + checkboxToFindAndChangeState);
                    if (checkbox.checked) {
                        checkboxToDisable.disabled = true;
                    } else {
                        checkboxToDisable.disabled = false;
                    }
                }
            },
```

It's very weird!
"Doesn't work" means that the loaded page behaves very unpredictable - it seems that not all data are loaded and the method setStateOfTheSameFactorsWithPlusAndMinus can't check some checkboxes correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `async mounted`, which cannot be done because lifecycle hooks are synchronous only, call an asynchronous method from mounted like this (remember async always requires await to return a promise):

```
mounted () {
   this.functionBlah();
}
```

...

```
methods: {
async functionBlah () {
    await actionX()
    .then(actionY)
    .then(actionZ)
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hmm ok but why I can't just write functionBlah().then(...) Do I need async and await? But anyway - works perfectly :)

Comment: Wrapping a function in a promise (which is what `async-await` is doing) means that your `then` statements will wait for the promise to resolve before executing. if you do not include `async`, using `then` is pointless because you would not be returning a promise beforehand. Think of it as "Resolve this promise, then do this."